# Does uploading with Silverlight suffer the cookie bug like flash?

Tags: asp.net, flash, silverlight, cookies

When using flash to upload a file to a web server, it sends cookies from IE only. This breaks things like session and FormsAuthentication in ASP.NET.

Does silverlight have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article, it may help,

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Cookies-in-Silverlight-Web-Requests.aspx

It says that cookies are transfered automatically, and if it does then it will not break FormsAuthentication

Comment: Does silverlight have the problem that flash has?